# Data validation excel offset of current cell for two columns SNR and REG

Tags: vba, excel, math, excel-formula

I am trying to with data validation in excel to get two columns in one column so to speak.  In the column I have circled blue I want to have the user pick Reg or SNR (circled red) and it will get the offset of the current cell.  I have tried `[![=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,5)][1]][1]` which works as the cell is always 5 to right. However it does not get the values under that but only that one cell.  It also of course excludes Reg values.
Is what I am after possible in Excel or do I have to do up a new table to incorporate SNR?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a named range for SNR and REG and use the below as the formula in the data validation rule:

```
=INDIRECT($O$5)
```

[image]

You can make the named range for REG dynamic like using the below:

```
=OFFSET($U$6,0,0,COUNTIF($U$6:$U$6000,">"&0),1)
```

And simply change the range and do the same for SNR
[image]

Comment: I have done this for SNR.  Is it possible to have it that by picking the title SNR or REG it will then do 
=OFFSET($U$6,0,0,COUNTIF($U$6:$U$6000,">"&0),1) of current column or 
=OFFSET($T$6,0,0,COUNTIF($T$6:$T$6000,">"&0),1) respectively in the one column.  It'd get confusing to read otherwise..

Comment: @JayRen by using the INDIRECT in the data validation it will choose which list to use

Comment: It displays SNR and Reg atm but when I go Formulas -> Define name and input that it just continues to read SNR and Reg.  Its like it doesn't save it

Comment: in cell O5 you will type either REG or SNR, then in )6 use the data validation as shown, at it should give you a list corresponding to the values uner each list

Comment: Hmm I honestly have no idea what I am doing wrong here.   Excel does not seem to like using the title and offsetting each column does not seem to like it

Comment: check out these links, they may be able to explain better than me http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html   http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are trying to do but let me know if this is not what you intended to do.

[image]

First, under `cell O5`, I set up a `Data Validation` like the pic above so the end user can pick either `SNR or Reg`.

[image]

Second, I used this `OFFSET` formula inside `Data Validation` to display the possible values under either `column T or U` based on the selection on `cell O5`:

```
=IF(O5="SNR",OFFSET($T$6,0,0,COUNTIF($T$6:$T$6000,">"&0),1),OFFSET($U$6,0,0,COUNTIF($U$6:$U$6000,">"&0),1))
```